# How to display cart details along with sub totals discount coupon code in magento checkout page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

> How to display cart details along with sub totals discount coupon code
>   etc inside shipping methods section in magento checkout page

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call this data by getting the quote:

```
<?php
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $cartData = $cart->getData();
?>
```

Then display e.g. the grand total:

```
<?php echo $cartData['grand_total']; ?>
```